# Replace all different dates in a formula with yesterday's date in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my macro to change the workbook (that has any dates into) referred to in a formula to another workbook (with today's date), both files are in the same filepath.

The tricky bit is that the date in the formula could be **any** date in the last 5 days, so I'm not able to specify a date to change when using the code below. I have tried treating it as text with Question Marks "??" to denote the length of the date (2020????), because the format of the date will be the same, but when the macro runs, it doesn't change the dates.

This is what I'm using now

```
    Dim TdyDt2 As String, YstDt2 As String
     Dim DateTdy As String, DateYtr As String
    TdyDt2 = "2020????"  'this is any date in last 5 days
   YstDt2 = Format(Date - 1, "yyyymmdd") 'this needs to be yesterday's date

   Range("B:N").Cells.Replace What:=YstDt2, Replacement:=TdyDt2, LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False
```

[Excel Workbook showing formula of file location with date that I am trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLfE8.png)
 NB: I know the formula is missing "=" this was just to get a screenshot.

So on Monday the macro should change "C:\Daily[Daily202005**29** F.csv]" to "C:\Daily[Daily202005**31** F.csv]" which would be Monday's yesterday.

If anyone has a suggestion, I'm happy to hear of it.

Comment: Why not just change the source through the [Edit links](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653) window?

Comment: Hmm I'll have a look and get back,  cheers for the quick response @BigBen

Comment: `TdyDt2` is referring to any date in the year 2020.  Is that OK?  Or are you specifically looking just for the previous 5 days?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for commenting, the date would be in the last 5 days, so the file name for today would be 20200601 (yyyymmdd)

Comment: Then just use @Viktor solution to check for any of the last five days.  You'll have to check five times, but that should not be an issue.

Comment: @BigBen I've had a look at the source which does work to manually change the links, but I was hoping for code to do t for me. At present I use Replace- which is easier than the Source as my reference files are .cvs and using the source option it won't show me any of my .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem really is how to go back for 5 days, then I would use the code below to get Today and any day before, like yesterday. Then I would repeat the search for all the last 5 days.

```
Dim dToday As Date
dToday = Date
Dim dYesterday As Date
dYesterday = Date - 1
```

Comment: Thanks @viktor, but it isn't just specifically 5 days,  the days could be anywhere in between this time frame. Which would mean I'd need to manually check what the formula refers to then run a macro specific to it. It is an option but I'd prefer the least amount of effort .

Comment: I meant, do a cycle to try every day 1-5. If a day was not found just skip to the next one.

Comment: Thanks @Viktor, I'll have a look to see if I can do an If, Else with this to look at the dates. Not a bad idea to have the vba check it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else that has this issue, I'm sorry, but I did not find a fitting solution.

What I have done is changed the way that I run the reports, so that it must be completed every day of the week.

I used @BigBen's suggestion to edit links:

```
    'replace the date with today's date
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink "N:\Folder\Daily" & Format$(Date - 1, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv", _
"N:\Folder\Daily" & Format$(Date - 1, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv", xlExcelLinks
```